# How to use Linux username and password with Subversion?

Tags: ubuntu, svn, authentication, pam

I'd like to setup Subversion repository so that same username and password could be used to access repository as in ssh login. I managed to get login work so that correct username is required, but it accepts any password. How I can get it to require valid password also?

I'm running Ubuntu server 8.04.2 with "standard modules", Apache2, Subversion and  libapache2-mod-authnz-external. In addition I found utility called [pwauth](http://code.google.com/p/pwauth/) to help with authentication.

Here are the relevant parts from configuration:

/etc/apache/apache2.conf

```
AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/local/bin/pwauth
SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
AddExternalGroup unixgroup /usr/local/bin/unixgroup
SetExternalGroupMethod unixgroup environment
```

/etc/apache/mods-available/dav_svn.conf:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider external
AuthExternal pwauth
GroupExternal unixgroup
AuthName "Subversion repository"
Require group users
Require user myaccount
```

/etc/pam.d/pwauth:

```
auth    required        pam_succeed_if.so user=www-data
account required        pam_localuser.so
```

config.h for pwauth:

```
#define PAM                     /* Linux PAM or OpenPAM*/
#define UNIX_LASTLOG            /**/
#define HAVE_LASTLOG_H          /**/
#define NOLOGIN_FILE "/etc/nologin"     /**/
#define MIN_NOLOGIN_UID 1               /**/
#define CHECK_LOGIN_EXPIRATION          /**/
#define CHECK_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION       /**/
#define SERVER_UIDS 33          /* user "www-data" */
#define MIN_UNIX_UID 500        /**/
#define SLEEP_LOCK "/var/run/pwauth.lock"
```

(is something missing?)

**Edit:** I'm aware about potential security issues, but I want know why this setup doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I have set this up before, and the way subversion works it would prompt you for your passwords hundreds of times during a session.

(To do this, simply connect your subversion client to **svn+ssh://username@servername/path/to/repo**)

The answer is to use ssh keys.

Set up your private/public key pair, and upload your public key to your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file, but prefix it with "command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r /path/to/repo"

And connect again using svn+ssh as mentioned above

Comment: TortoiseSVN remembers the authentication information. Not the safest solution, but ok for current use.

Comment: Yeah, but SSH keys give better security with less hassle, once set up.

Comment: Bad idea to use svn+ssh for a multi-user setup, it will create you a lot of trouble with permissions (for instance, files created by one user won't be modifiable by the others, depending on the umask). See "The svn+ssh:// Server Checklist" in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html

Comment: Good point - I remember we had to do a bit of permissions tweaking when we first set this up.

Comment: When using `command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r /path/to/repo"` the user/key combination is bound to one repo, is there a secure way to allow the same user to access multiple repos?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.  Do not use login passwords in potentially less secure applications.  Use ssh keys like Brent says.

Answer (score 0):

avoid apache altogether and use svn+ssh protocol

Comment: Bad idea, it will create you a lot of trouble with permissions (for instance, files created by one user won't be modifiable by the others, depending on the umask). See "The svn+ssh:// Server Checklist" in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html